# Getting different values from a property at design and run time

Tags: c#, design-time

I'd like a property in my class to return a different value at design time than in run time. I can detect that I'm in design mode using [`LicenseManager.UsageMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.licensemanager.usagemode.aspx), but it would be nice to exclude that from my Release builds.

Is there a better way to implement the following code, perhaps using the [`Conditional`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) attribute somehow?

```
public int MyValue
{
    get
    {
        int my_value = 10;

#if DEBUG
        if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
        {
            my_value = 20;
        }
#endif

        return my_value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the DesignTime property?  It should have the right value in a property getter.

Comment: @Hans, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you provide a link or be more specific?

Comment: If you don't know what I mean then you should use this.DesignTime instead.  LicenseManager has an iffy hack around not having DesignTime initialized yet in the constructor.

Comment: I don't have a DesignTime property defined anywhere, and I can't find any documentation about a DesignTime property on MSDN. There is a DesignMode property on WinForms controls, but I'm using WPF, and I want to detect design time in a non-control class anyways. In WPF I could do a DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())...

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will be a check you have to make. Or, if the two are totally different programs that you build seperately, you can do the same `#if` for your custom variables.

So if there are two seperate builds, you can set a custom parameter for building and do this:

```
public int MyValue
{
    get
    {

#if DESIGN
        return 20;
#else 
        return 10;
#endif

    }
}
```